# Has this formula been discovered before? $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}ax^{-b}=a(-1)^n\frac{(b+n-1)!}{(b-1)!}x^{-b-n}$, given

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I came across this formula doing a homework problem:

> $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}ax^{-b}=a(-1)^n\frac{(b+n-1)!}{(b-1)!}x^{-b-n}$$

Has this been discovered or proofed before (my proof is below, definitely not rigorous as I don't know how to write an actual proof).

> **Claim.** $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}ax^{-b}=a(-1)^n\frac{(b+n-1)!}{(b-1)!}x^{-b-n}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $b, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.
>
> **Proof.** $$\begin{align} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}ax^{-b}&=a(-b)(-b-1)(-b-2)...(-b-(n-1))x^{-b-n} \\
> &=a(-1)(b)(-1)(b+1)(-1)(b+2)...(-1)(b+n-1)x^{-b-n} \\
> &=a\underbrace{(-1)(-1)(-1)...(-1)}_{\text{n terms}}\underbrace{b(b+1)(b+2)...(b+n-1)}_{\text{series multiplied together}}x^{-b-n} \\
> &=a(-1)^n\frac{(b+n-1)!}{(b-1)!}x^{-b-n}
> \end{align}$$

Comment: Do you know how to prove by induction?  If so, this can be seen by induction on $n$.

Comment: This is a well known result, yes, and your proof is well-written.

Comment: Why starting from power of $-b$ , why bother to have $a$?

Comment: Thanks everyone, both for the verification and for the induction tip.